# Error with building associations in FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have this factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :asset_size do 

    sequence(:name) { |n| "AssetSize#{n}" }  

    after_create do |as|
      FactoryGirl.create(:midpoint, :asset_size => as)
      FactoryGirl.create(:midpoint, :asset_size => as, :grade => 18, :yearly_wage => 25000.00)
    end

  end
end
```

but keep getting this error:

```
AssetSize(#70166742384960) expected, got #<Class:0x007fa1eddef738>(#70166728637340)   (ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch) ./spec/factories/asset_size_factory.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in './features/step_definitions/role_authorization_steps.rb:2:in `/^a basic balanced results employee$/'./features/role_authorization.feature:4:in `Given a basic balanced results employee'

after_create do |as|
  FactoryGirl.create(:midpoint, :asset_size => as)
  FactoryGirl.create(:midpoint, :asset_size => as, :grade => 18, :yearly_wage => 25000.00)
```

I underatand the error, but I don't understand how my syntax is off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't the syntax: `after(:create) { this_runs_first }` so i wonder if it will work if you do it that way.

Comment: dude i've been debugging crap like this all this week, now help me with my problems! ;-) glad it worked.